# SET WHERE in IF Statement in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following Stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root` @` % ` PROCEDURE `getQuotesReport` (
  IN datebegin DATETIME,
  IN dateend DATETIME,
  IN userID INT
) 
SELECT 
  q1.id,
  q1.rate,
  q1.insurer,
  dealershipcompany.NAME AS 'dealershipName',
  q1.createdAt,
  STATUS.STATUS AS 'Status',
  (SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(" ", u2.firstName, u2.lastName) 
  FROM
    quotelog 
    INNER JOIN USER u2 
      ON (quotelog.createdBy = u2.id) 
  WHERE quotelog.STATUS = 1 
    AND quotelog.quote = q1.id 
  GROUP BY q1.id) AS `creatorName`,
  (SELECT 
    u2.ROLE 
  FROM
    quotelog 
    INNER JOIN USER u2 
      ON (quotelog.createdBy = u2.id) 
  WHERE quotelog.STATUS = 1 
    AND quotelog.quote = q1.id 
  GROUP BY q1.id) AS `creatorRole`,
  client.NAME AS 'clientName',
  client.dob,
  CONCAT_WS(" ", u1.firstName, u1.lastName) AS `brokerName` 
FROM
  quoteq1 
  INNER JOIN CLIENT 
    ON client.id = q1.client 
  LEFT JOIN dealershipcompany 
    ON dealershipcompany.id = q1.dealershipCompany 
  INNER JOIN quotelog 
    ON quotelog.quote = q1.id 
  LEFT JOIN USER u1 
    ON u1.id = quotelog.assignedTo 
  LEFT JOIN USER u2 
    ON (quotelog.createdBy = u2.id) 
  INNER JOIN STATUS 
    ON STATUS.id = quotelog.STATUS 
WHERE quotelog.assignedTo = userID 
  AND (
    q1.createdAt BETWEEN datebegin 
    AND dateend
  ) 
ORDER BY q1.createdAt DESC
```

I want set where depending if VAR userID is NULL or not

for example if userID is NULL , I replace the where statement with the following:

```
WHERE q1.createdAt BETWEEN datebegin AND dateend
```

in the nutshell, I want it to look like this

```
IF NULL(userID) THEN SET WHERE q1.createdAt BETWEEN datebegin AND dateend
ELSE SET  WHERE quotelog.assignedTo =  userID AND (q1.createdAt BETWEEN datebegin AND dateend)
```

I don't know if this feasible in Mysql, I tried different ways but always get syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
...
WHERE (quotelog.assignedTo = userID OR userID IS NULL)
  AND (q1.createdAt BETWEEN datebegin  AND dateend)
```

If `userID` is provided it will return rows assigned to specified user, if not it will return for all users.

Second condtion will filter records based on date range.

---

Another way is to use `COALESCE`:

```
...
WHERE quotelog.assignedTo = COALESCE(userID,quotelog.assignedTo)
  AND (q1.createdAt BETWEEN datebegin  AND dateend)
```

---

If `quotelog.assignedTo` is `nullable`:

```
...
WHERE COALESCE(quotelog.assignedTo,-1) = COALESCE(userID,quotelog.assignedTo,-1)
  AND (q1.createdAt BETWEEN datebegin  AND dateend)
```

where number like `-1` should be invalid `userId`

Comment: Wow, the answer is simpler than I thought,thanks, this is correct answer but SO tells me to wait  10 minutes to flag it as such.

Comment: Actually there still a little problem and that is only get userID with NULL value if the userID was null,  it doesn't return  all users.